# frame passed to lookupTransform does not exist

Tags: ros, frame, transforms, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have encountered a peculiar error with the tf. The python `lookupTransform` function throws an exception saying that requested frame does not exists whereas tools like tf_echo do not report any problems. Since the setup I am trying to run is extremely simple, I have no idea what could be wrong. Either I have missed something very simple which I can't see right now or this is a bug in tf.

I am running stage with the willow-erratic.world file:
`rosrun stage_ros stageros -g willow-erratic.world` 
together with the following node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import tf
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan

listener = tf.TransformListener()

def scanCb(msg):
        print 'laserscan received'
        print msg.angle_max   

        # lookup base_link -> laser frame transformation
        (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('base_link', 'base_laser_link', rospy.Time())

rospy.init_node('console_interface')
rospy.Subscriber('/base_scan', LaserScan, scanCb)
rospy.spin()
```

The output is:

```
laserscan received
2.35837626457
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424179111.916555] [4010.900000] bad callback: <function scanCb at 0x7fa22abe2cf8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 688, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/vagrant/test_ws/src/scout_nav/scripts/console_iface", line 14, in scanCb
    (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform('base_link', 'base_laser_link', rospy.Time())
LookupException: "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

tf_echo does not seem to have problems with looking up the transform:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo base_link base_laser_link
At time 4147.200
- Translation: [0.050, 0.000, 0.250]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with my approach?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203274/frame-passed-to-lookuptransform-does-not-exist/) by [Yorick](https://answers.ros.org/users/21661/yorick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out what was causing the problem...

The call `listener = tf.TransformListener()` should be after the node initialization.

---

Originally posted by [Yorick](https://answers.ros.org/users/21661/yorick/) with karma: 116 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
Yeah that is definitely a problem as well! I missed that :) ... I do believe my answer still provides several useful tips.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
I'm quite sure that even if you swap the order of the listener creation and the call to `init_node`, your node will occasionally crash with the same error you originally presented if, just by chance, the `/base_scan` topic gets published immediately after the creation of the Subscriber.

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-05**:
For what it's worth, I was having this error about `target_frame` not existing and played with incantations of where to define `listener`, but my issue ended up being [this one](http://answers.ros.org/question/231914/tf_echo-can-find-transform-but-waitfortransform-cant/). Namely, use `tf2`.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2019-06-30**:
Also worth noting, it seems that sometimes if you call `lookupTransform` too quickly after `init_node` you will get the error shown in the original question. To deal with this, you can use `waitForTransform` first, e.g.:

```
listener = tf.TransformListener()
listener.waitForTransform("/frame1", "/frame2", rospy.Time(), rospy.Duration(4.0))
(trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform("/frame1", "/frame2", rospy.Time(0))
```

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2021-03-08**:
I had a similar issue and adding `rospy.Duration(4)` was essential

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As a first debugging step, I'd recommend wrapping your call to `lookupTransform` in a try-except block. Just like they do in lines 23-26 of the [Python tf listener tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29#The_Code). After the creation of the listener, it usually takes a few seconds to negotiate all of the connections, and to get the listener to start filling its buffers. I'm guessing that you are seeing your error because you are asking for a transform too soon after the creation of the listener.

Another thing you could do is [wait for the transform](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28Python%29#tf.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-tf_and_Time_.28C.2B-.2B-.29-1.Wait_for_transforms) to become available before requesting a lookup.

As a final note, be aware that even if all of your tf code is functioning properly, due to the asynchronous nature of ROS, your call to `lookupTransform` is likely to fail occasionally. This is usually because of timing issues. I always wrap calls to `lookupTransform` in a try and except block of some sort.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/20013/arkin/) on 2020-04-27**:
Good explanation, and thanks!